# Elasticsearch Error 429 without actually sending any bulk data

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have a weird problem. I'm using [Elasticsearch-Inside](https://github.com/lexCerveza/Elasticsearch-Inside), a package to embed an elasticsearch node with your integration tests, so you can fire up one server per test, do your testing and then get rid of it and fire up a new one for the next test. So far, it's very simple, I only have a single test and a single node.

When I run my test I get the following exception:

**Message:**

> Elasticsearch.Net.ElasticsearchClientException: 
> Request failed to execute. 
> Call: Status code 429 
> from: HEAD /my_index_name?pretty=true&error_trace=true

**Stack Trace:**

```
Transport`1.HandleElasticsearchClientException(RequestData data, Exception clientException, IElasticsearchResponse response)
Transport`1.FinalizeResponse[TResponse](RequestData requestData, IRequestPipeline pipeline, List`1 seenExceptions, TResponse response)
Transport`1.RequestAsync[TResponse](HttpMethod method, String path, CancellationToken cancellationToken, PostData data, IRequestParameters requestParameters)
SearchCacheUsingElasticSearch.EnsureIndexCreatedAsync(Boolean wipe, String indexName, Func`2 mappingFunction) line 56
SearchCacheUsingElasticSearch.EnsureCreatedAsync(Boolean wipe) line 73
EnsureCreatedHostedService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) line 42
TestEnvironment.CreateAsync(Action`1 action, String testCase) line 149
IntegrationTests.TestWithTestData() line 35
ThreadOperations.ExecuteWithAbortSafety(Action action)
```

I understand that http code 429 is used for rate limiting and in the case of elastic search to signal that there was too much bulk data and it has to be processed before more can be received by the node.

But both the Stacktrace and the error message tell me that I got this error on my very first call, basically querying just if the index I intent to use exists (because if it doesn't, I would create it as a next step).

Just for completeness, this is my line of code, it uses the NEST client and really does not have a lot of options I could mess up:

```
var existsResponse = await this.client.Indices.ExistsAsync(indexName);
```

The error message aboves proves that it does generate the correct json to send to the server.

How can my first call of "does this index here exist" possibly be too much data and need rate limiting? I don't understand the error. Does someone have an explanation for what goes wrong here? Does Elasticsearch maybe use http: 429 for other errors, too? I could not find anything about it in the documentation.

I turned on logging for Elasticsearch-Inside and saw that it was initialized properly, but nothing about any calls was logged.

Comment: Could you share your test as well?

Comment: as well as your Elasticsearch config, including things like heap size :)